# Using JFileChooser? Java

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

So I need to open a java file to read through it and check if the number of parentheses are even (as much ( as )). This gives me an error saying no instance of `OpenFile` is in the scope. I copied this code, so I have no idea whats wrong with it. I would also like to know how to access a file and read through it? I don't know how to use `JFileChooser` at all and can't find anything online that I understand.

```
public class BraceChecker {
    public static void main (String [] args){
        final JFileChooser fc= new JFileChooser();
        int response= fc.showOpenDialog(OpenFile.this)
    }
}
```

Comment: See the [JFileChooser API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html) for an example. And [How to Use File Choosers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) for a tutorial

Comment: What do you use as the parameters of show open dialog?

Comment: Look at the API. That's what the link is for. A Java (or any) developer needs to learn how to read documentation.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#showDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: *"can't find anything online that I understand"*  Why should we try explaining again, then?  It is likely you will not understand us.  Link to the things you found and explain what you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
jf.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY); //set the selection (files/directorys)
jf.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.jpg; *.gif","jpg","gif"));//set the file extensions (jpg,gif)
int response = jf.showOpenDialog(null); //shows the open-dialog and get the response
if (response == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { //only when the user click on open, do this:
   File file = jf.getSelectedFile(); //get the choosen file
   //...
}
```

If you want to have a save dialog, you can write:

```
jf.showSaveDialog(null);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have placed your code directly in the class. You need to put your code in a method.

Comment: Sorry I'll edit, I just copied this incorrectly, can you explain how to use JFileChooser?